# IndexError: list assignment index out of range.

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code raises an `IndexError`, can anyone explain why the logic of this code does not work?

```
midterms = [90, 80, 89, 87, 97, 100]
for mark in midterms:
    newMark = mark + 2
    midterms[mark] = newMark
print(midterms)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using the values contained in the list as indices; `mark` takes the values `90, 80, ..., 100`. The subscription `midterm[90]` is obviously out of bounds.

To iterate through the items while also having a handle on the position, Python offers `enumerate` which provides an index along with the current value:

```
midterms = [90, 80, 89, 87, 97, 100]
for ind, mark in enumerate(midterms):
    newMark = mark + 2
    midterms[ind] = newMark
print(midterms)
```

This, in effect, allows iterating through the list and changing it effortlessly.

Comment: I guess you could also use the `range(len(midterms))` function.

Comment: @Jerrybibo you could be you really shouldn't. This is exactly why `enumerate` exists.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of this if you're new to python (I didn't know about enumerate as a beginner) is to use Jerrybibo's suggestion. Code for that would look like this:

```
midterms = [90, 80, 89, 87, 97, 100]
for i in range(len(midterms)):
    newMark = midterms[i] + 2
    midterms[i] = newMark
print(midterms)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41133312/7204790) and I share the same answer. Another workaround for your code is this:

```
midterms = [90, 80, 89, 87, 97, 100]
print [mark+2 for mark in midterms]
```

which shall also yield

`[92, 82, 91, 89, 99, 102]`

[python](/questions/tagged/python)